# Exception handling - Can't catch 'SyntaxError : Missing initializer in const declaration'

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I learnt about hoisting in JavaScript , and wanted to experiment the kind of errors i could get , and to catch them. However i can't figure out how to catch this precise error:

```
SyntaxError : Missing initializer in const declaration.
```

Here is the piece of code:

```
try {
    g = 'Hello !';
    console.log(g);
    const g;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('You got an error '+err);
  }
  console.log('rest of the code.')
```

I tested this try-catch with other exceptions, and everything seemed to work correctly. So I thought the problem was about hoisting and maybe variables were read right at the start of the block hence were not caught.

I tried to encapsulate the whole code in a try-catch but without any conclusive results. Here is my code encapsulated:

```
function hoisting() {
  try {
    g = 'Hello !';
    console.log(g);
    const g;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('You got an error '+err);
  }
  console.log('rest of the code.');
}

function main() {
  try {
  hoisting();
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: `const g;` is a **syntax** error, nothing that can be caught. The code doesn't even run, because it could not be parsed correctly; it's not a valid program. It must be `const g = something;` or `let g;`.

Comment: You can't; it's a syntax error.

Comment: @Bergi ok thanks a lot , I don't know why i thought i could catch any exceptions with the try-catch and didn't know the parser acted this way. that's nice to know : )

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks as well for the answer and the correction !